# stop recursion after index is passed

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to write my own version of radix sort, I am currently at a roadblock not being able to return final value

```
def radix_sort(arr, n, di=None):
    if not di:
        arr = [str(i) for i in arr]
        di = {str(i): [] for i in range(10)}
        maximum = max([len(i) for i in arr])
    else:
        maximum = di
        di = {str(i): [] for i in range(10)}
    for i in arr:
        temp = i[-n]
        di[temp].append(i)
    print(di)
    return radix_sort([v for i in di.values() for v in i], n + 1, maximum)


x = [329, 457, 657, 839, 436, 720, 355]
print(radix_sort(x, 1))
```

currently it does sort but at the last iteration it throws an Index error, and I am not sure how to stop it

Answer (score 0):

You are not using any termination in your code. You can return the array rightaway if `n` exceeds `maximum`. (Also, passing maximum as argument is unnecessary)

Here is a modified code:

```py
def radix_sort(arr, n, di=None):
    if not di:
        arr = [str(i) for i in arr]
        di = {str(i): [] for i in range(10)}
        maximum = max([len(i) for i in arr])
    else:
        maximum = di
        di = {str(i): [] for i in range(10)}
    if n>maximum:
        return arr
    for i in arr:
        temp = i[-n]
        di[temp].append(i)
    #print(di)
    return radix_sort([v for i in di.values() for v in i], n + 1)

x = [329, 457, 657, 839, 436, 720, 355]
print(radix_sort(x, 1))
```

And the output would be:

```py
['329', '355', '436', '457', '657', '720', '839']
```

Comment: this will enter the `if n > maximum` two times right (in this example list)?